# Enable anonymous bind in openldap

Tags: openldap

I have setup ldap server successfully on centos 7, It works fine. However, i cannot access the server with 'anonymous' bind, which according to every google search it should be.

When I execute;

## ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com

output says;

## result: 50 Insufficient access

**Note:** the only ACL exist is;

```
olcAccess: {0}to *
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
```

does this prove server don't configured to support 'anonymous' bind.?
And if so, can you list out way of which how to enable 'anonymous' bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous bind is enabled, but your ACL prohibits most anonymous action via `by * none`. What your ACL should look like will depend on your environment and your goals. Generally speaking anonymous access means your offering a public service or haven't thought through what you're trying to accomplish.

You should familiarize yourself with [`OpenLDAP's Access Control Documenation`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html).